# Local modified version of remote immutable database

Tags: database, oracle, transactions

**What I want:** A local database that acts as a view of a remote database. The remote database is immutable, but the local database can be updated. Both can be queried, the remote database in pristine state, the local database in updated state.

This behavior is very similar to when you have an uncommitted transaction. You can query the database in updated state, but the database remains unchanged (until commit/rollback). The main difference is that I would like for the transaction to be accessible from multiple connections.

Notes:

- "Local" and "remote" are not compulsory. They are simply two separate entities.
- The local database might not be a database at all or even separate from the remote database (e.g. a transaction).

**Use case:** I am doing automated testing. Frequently, at my company, my automated tests fail because someone messed up data (for testing) which I expect not to be changed. Data setup during automation is possible but not ideal because the size of the static data is very large.

Every once in a while, the data in our testing environment becomes corrupted enough that we decide to wipe it and reload the data. I imagine that being able to have "views" of the database would allow us to keep the database clean but still semi-modifiable.

**Possible approaches:**

- I have tried some Googling, but I'm not sure what terms to Google for.
- Implement a server myself which opens transactions with the remote database and exposes endpoints for clients to interact with the open transaction. I am not a big fan of this solution, and I am not a database expert so I do not know the ins and outs of transactions. Does this sound like a terrible idea?
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you need the two databases to be separate?  It sounds like you are describing would be something that Oracle Workspace Manager would support http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14253/long_intro.htm  That supports long-term collaborative management of changes to a data set which sounds like what you want but would be all in the same database.

Comment: It doesn't have to been a completely separate database. I just imagined it separately to ensure that the original data remained unchanged. Thanks for the link! Workspace Manager sounds like exactly what I need. Do you have any idea about its performance with very large databases?

Comment: It depends on things like how much data is changing, how many workspaces you have, etc.  Workspace Manager was originally built for people that were working with Spatial data sets where you'd have dozens of people collaborating, say, on laying out all the infrastructure for a new subdivision in a workspace while other people see the live data.

Comment: If you convert your comment into an answer, I can accept it for you. I haven't tried Workspace Manager yet (not a DBA at my company), but it sounds like a good lead.